# Raspberry Pi 4: Uneven speed of GPIO bit-banging in C loop (RPi 4, 64bit)

Tags: raspberry-pi, profiling, gpio, raspberry-pi4

I am trying to measure the data transfer speed achievable through GPIO bit-banging and recording the reading results in memory. I have created a [writeup](https://alexandersavochkin.github.io/posts/fpga-driven-data-streaming-into-raspberry-pi-speed-and-timing-stability-part-1/) on the setup, it uses FPGA connected to GPIO [1](https://alexandersavochkin.github.io/posts/fpga-driven-data-streaming-into-raspberry-pi-speed-and-timing-stability-part-1/).

I use the following approach: GPIO0 to GPIO20 are dedicated to 'data', while GPIO25 to GPIO27 are designated for 'control signals' such as 'data ready', 'data request', and 'reset'.

The loop is simple:

1. RPi sets "data request" to high
2. FPGA detects "data request" and sets data @ GPIO0-20 (the data is 50MHz counting timer value, so it allows me to measure the speed).
3. FPGA sets "data ready" level to HIGH
4. RPI detects "data ready" HIGH level, reads the data and writes into a buffer in RAM
5. RPI sets "data request" to LOW. Upon receiving low "data request", FPGA sets data ready to LOW.
6. GOTO 1

I've found that first ~60-70K reads are ~0.88 uS per cycle, but then it gets more than twice faster, ~0.38 uS per cycle.

I am wondering what the reason behind this uneven speed is. Is there a way to start the transfer at this higher speed of 0.38 uS per cycle and be sure that it won't fall back to the slower 0.88 uS mode?

Comment: After some searching on the web, I started thinking that it might be due to Dynamic Voltage and Frequency Scaling. My hypothesis is that it takes some time for the System/CPU to uderstand that it runs under higher load and boost the CPU clock. Investigating

Comment: You have to run RTOS for that. GPIO is worst choice for such a task.

Comment: @0andriy the whole point of my work was assessing feasibility of it using GPIO/Linux for "quick" data transfer from an external device to RPi and it looks like it is a kind of [viable option](https://alexandersavochkin.github.io/posts/fpga-driven-data-streaming-into-raspberry-pi-speed-and-timing-stability-part-1/).

Could you elaborate why GPIO is the worst choice here?

Comment: Each edge switching requires a lot of IO on a locked bus, between which you have absolutely no guarantee on the duration, because you are not using RTOS. Even if the latter is the case, see the former part of the sentence.

Answer (score 0):

I have confirmed that it is due to DVFS.

I found that by default when a core is idle in RPi4, it's frequency set to 600MHz, and increased to 1800MHz when it is under load. It looks like it takes approximately 50-60 mS for the system to react to increased load.

With scaling governor set to "performance" instead of the default "ondemand" value, the exchange speed is fast from the very beginning.

Comment: Just luck, still there is no guarantee at all for the duration in non-RTOS.